# Bluetooth - Is a sending a message over Bluetooth to a hardware device from a PC and from an Android Device the same thing?

Tags: android, bluetooth, serial-port

A current project I am working on involves sending serial Bluetooth data from a PC application to a hardware device.

If I was to send that same serial Bluetooth data but from an Android device,

How does that look from the device's point of view?  Will it receive anything different caused by either the PC or Android medium or will the message received be the same regardless?

Basically is anything involved in compensating for where the data came from?

Cheers

Comment: does your music sound different when played from Android and PC to the same bt headphones? even if there were differences in the parts of the protocol you can't modify these should not be treated as data in your device

Comment: I don't really get what you are saying in the last part of your answer.. What your saying is that the data packets once in transmission will be for all intensive purposes the same? With the same destination and data allowing for just one data processing algorithm on the device?

Comment: correct. There is pairing and device data that goes between the devices that will be different but it should be irrelevant to your device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeems like you are using the Bluetooth Serial port profile from the PC to connect to your hardware. And if you use the same profile you can send the data from any device and the same application on your hardware should handle it. 
So yes you can use the android bluetooth socket interface to crreate and connect to the hardware and it should also work.